# Не могу добавить активити в собственный Layout

Tags: android, activity, android-layout

Активити меню с лайоутом.

При нажатии кнопки хочу, чтобы активити приложения открывалась в лайоуте (чтобы можно было добавить быстро оформление и навигацию).
Только я сначала написал активити, а теперь не могу никак его засунуть в лайоут.

Приводить код меню не буду - там вызов активити интентом.

Меню - GameActivity - ApplicationView:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new ApplicationView(this));
        //setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
    }
}
```

и вот вторая

```
public class ApplicationView<yLine> extends View {

    public ApplicationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Config.ARGB_4444);
        canvas = new Canvas(image);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.translate(position.x, position.y);
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, paint);
        }
    }
```

... далее пошли эвенты и прочие няшки

Что Вы посоветуете? 
Думаю логи вам пока не нужны, потому что все подряд, возможно, неправильно.

Comment: А что конкретно не так... в каком месте падает, какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: непонятно что пишет. пробовал воттакой лайоут     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.rdt.touched.game.ApplicationView
        android:id="@+id/game_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>  в графической вьюшке в эклипсе писал про isInEditMode. в интернете ничего понятного не нашел. есль один пример. и он везде. как подключить не понял.

Comment: я бы хотел помощь из того что есть. если возможно. ну конечно логи выложу если что не так пойдет

Comment: То что Eclipse пишет не столь важно. Какие ошибки комниляции или выполнения?

Comment: запутал тут немного . ща заново сформулирую и открою новый вопрос... извините

Comment: @РоманЗыков если заплутали, читайте справку )) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы собственное `View` можно было создавать из разметки (XML layout), нужно имплементировать конструктор с двумя параметрами. В вашем случае:

```
public ApplicationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ...
}
```

Вот тут целая лекция обо всем этом.
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: а какже в активити указываешь лайоут, потом к примеру текствью и потом в поле текста вставляешь данные? получается что лайоут не создан в активити и вызывается функцией из активити?

Comment: Вы уже всех запутали :) Задайте вопрос снова и приведите в вопросе код, разметку и лог ошибок. Потому что сейчас у вас в коде одно, а в ваших комментах и логах другое.

Answer (score 1):

все заработало

вот код

```
private Level2 view;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);

   RelativeLayout layout = 
           (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_relativelayuot);
            view = new Level2(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout); 
            layout.addView(view, 0);
}
```

и во View

```
public Level2(Context context, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, RelativeLayout layout) {
            super(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Активити это компонент. Проще говоря ваше окно с логикой отображения макета, функциональной логикой. Его нельзя засунуть в лэйаут. Это макет (лэйаут) может быть отображен в активити/фрагменте. Если вам нужно объединить разметку то можно сделать это тегами include или добавить в разметку фрагмент.

Comment: Да это он неверно сформулировал, терминологию попутал. :) У него проблема с использованием custom view из разметки.

Comment: Хорошо бы разбираться в терминах сперва :) или задать вопрос на тему.

Comment: я немножко совсем новичок в java. больше в php.  вот если я делаю такой запускаемую активити public class GameActivity extends Activity {
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new ApplicationView(this));
        setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
    }                то вот ошибка из LogCatа

Comment: 02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rdt.touched/com.rdt.touched.game.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.rdt.touched.game.ApplicationView
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)

Comment: 02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: 02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at

Comment: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.rdt.touched.game.ApplicationView
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at

Comment: android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:508)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at

Comment: android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1742)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at com.rdt.touched.game.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:29)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  ... 11 more
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Comment: 02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ApplicationView(Context,AttributeSet)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
02-25 13:02:22.919: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)

Comment: что то мало символов можно вставить а кода много ...

Comment: Вот это `setContentView(new ApplicationView(this));` с этим `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.rdt.touched.game.ApplicationView` не стыкуется. Не может быть `InflateException` если вы свою вьюху в коде через вызов конструктора создаете.